# How to count the number of times an item occurs in a list base on another list

Tags: python, algorithm

suppose I have two lists as follows:

```
list1 = ["a","b","a","a","b","a","b","a","b","b","b"]
list2 = ["pos","neg","pos","neu","neg","pos","pos","pos","neg","neu","pos"]
```

I want to count the number of times `"pos"`,`"neg"` and `"neu"` has occurred for each item in `list1`.

So the number of times `"pos","neg"` and `"neu"` occurs with `"a"`, and for `"b"`. For example, the first element in `list1`, `"a"` has a `"pos"` value because `list2[0]` is for `"pos"`.

What is the best approach for this? I feel there is a much better solution out there in comparison to what I have done at the moment. I can see that if more unique items exist in `list1` my approach will not be feasible.

```py
list1 = ["a","b","a","a","b","a","b","a","b","b","b"]
list2 = ["pos","neg","pos","neu","neg","pos","pos","pos","neg","neu","pos"]

a_pos = 0
a_neg = 0
a_neu = 0
b_pos = 0
b_neg = 0
b_neu = 0

for i in range(len(list1)):
    if list1[i] == "a":
        if list2[i] == "pos":
            a_pos +=1
        elif list2[i] == "neg":
            a_neg +=1
        else:
            a_neu +=1
    if list1[i] == "b":
        if list2[i] == "pos":
            b_pos +=1
        elif list2[i] == "neg":
            b_neg +=1
        else:
            b_neu +=1       

print(a_pos,a_neg,a_neu)
print(b_pos,b_neg,b_neu)
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) with `zip`:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(zip(list1, list2))

Counter({('a', 'pos'): 4,
         ('b', 'neg'): 3,
         ('a', 'neu'): 1,
         ('b', 'pos'): 2,
         ('b', 'neu'): 1})
```

---

Where `zip` is creating an iterable with the elements from both lists interleaved:

```
[('a', 'pos'), ('b', 'neg'), ('a', 'pos'),...
```

So the above works because `zip` is returning tuples, which *are hashable*, a necessary condition for `Counter` to work as its elements are stored as a dictionary

Answer (score 6):

You can [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the two lists together, and then use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count your co-occurences

```
from collections import Counter
list1 = ["a","b","a","a","b","a","b","a","b","b","b"]
list2 = ["pos","neg","pos","neu","neg","pos","pos","pos","neg","neu","pos"]

print(Counter(zip(list1, list2)))
```

The output will be

```
{('a', 'pos'): 4, ('b', 'neg'): 3, ('a', 'neu'): 1, ('b', 'pos'): 2, ('b', 'neu'): 1}
```

To break it down, `zip` takes both of your lists, and create an iterator with elements each from each of the lists interleaved

```
In [1]: from collections import Counter 
   ...: list1 = ["a","b","a","a","b","a","b","a","b","b","b"] 
   ...: list2 = ["pos","neg","pos","neu","neg","pos","pos","pos","neg","neu","pos"]                                                                                                                     

In [2]: list(zip(list1,list2))                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[2]: 
[('a', 'pos'),
 ('b', 'neg'),
 ('a', 'pos'),
 ('a', 'neu'),
 ('b', 'neg'),
 ('a', 'pos'),
 ('b', 'pos'),
 ('a', 'pos'),
 ('b', 'neg'),
 ('b', 'neu'),
 ('b', 'pos')]
```

We then take this output, and put in into a `Counter`, which calculate the frequency of each item in the iterator and provides us a dictionary, this is possible because the key of the dictionary is a `tuple` which is a hashable type.

```
In [3]: Counter(list(zip(list1,list2)))                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[3]: 
Counter({('a', 'pos'): 4,
         ('b', 'neg'): 3,
         ('a', 'neu'): 1,
         ('b', 'pos'): 2,
         ('b', 'neu'): 1})
```

Comment: Good one. Can you please add some details?

Comment: Hi @SwadhikarC I have added details of how the code works. Please take a look and check if it makes sense :)