# How can I make a list with the times that an integer occurs in another list?

Tags: python

I wrote some code (Python) that prints that expresses a number in prime numbers. Here is the code that I have:

```
n = 24
lst=[]
i = 2
while n>1:
    if n%i==0:
      lst.append(i)
      n=n/i
      i-=1
    i+=1  
print(lst)
```

For example when my `n` is `24`, the output from the list is `[2,2,2,3]`, because `2*2*2*3=24`. Now I want to make a list that gives how many times a number occurs in my list. So for this example I want that my output is: `[3,1]`, because 2 occurs 3 times in my list en 3 occurs one time in my list. I have no idea how I can do this. When I uses the function count(), it prints `[3,3,3,1]`, because it checks the other list and checks for each item in it how often it exists, so also for the second and third item, which is the same as the first. Does anyone know how my code must look in order to have the output `[3,1]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count the number of times an item occurs in a list base on another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56168182/how-to-count-the-number-of-times-an-item-occurs-in-a-list-base-on-another-list)

Comment: No it didn't, but @thisisrandy answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a datatype called a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) in the standard library. Given an input iterable, it will output a dictionary of `{ value: count of value }` pairs. You can use it as follows (output is from the [ipython](https://ipython.org/) [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop)):

```py
In [1]: from collections import Counter

In [2]: primes = [2,2,2,3]

In [3]: counts = Counter(primes)

In [4]: counts
Out[4]: Counter({2: 3, 3: 1})

In [5]: counts.values()
Out[5]: dict_values([3, 1])

In [6]: list(counts.values())
Out[6]: [3, 1]
```

For illustrative purposes, let's also construct this manually using a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects):

```py
In [7]: from collections import defaultdict

In [8]: counts = defaultdict(int)

In [9]: for p in primes:
   ...:     counts[p] += 1
   ...:

In [10]: counts
Out[10]: defaultdict(int, {2: 3, 3: 1})

In [11]: counts.values()
Out[11]: dict_values([3, 1])

In [12]: list(counts.values())
Out[12]: [3, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter

lst = [2,2,2,3]
c = Counter(lst) # Counter({2: 3, 3: 1})
```

To get the count of a value:

```
c[2]  # count of 2 is 3
```

Comment: Okay thanks, but is it possible to multiply 3 with 1? So the times it is in the list.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Do you want to output `[3, 3, 3, 1]`?

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm not very clear to you. I mean my lst is `[2,2,2,3]`. The number `2` occurs `3` times in the list, so the first number of my new list must be `[3]`. Number 3 from my list `[2,2,2,3]`, occurs just once, so the second number of my new list must be `1`. So my new list needs to be `[3,1]`. But I have my answer already thanks to @thisisrandy