# accessing values() in collection.Counter as a list

Tags: python

I have this:

```
lst = [2,2,3,3]
c1 = Counter(lst)
x = c1.values()
```

I want to know why I get this:

```
x = dict_values([2, 2])
```

and what can i do to get this:

```
x = [2,2]
```

I want to do this so I can manipulate and compare the data inside, the only way I have found is by doing

```
x = []
for i in c1.values():
   x.append(i)
```

but I was looking for a more direct way to do this, like

```
x = c1.values()
```

I tried looking on the net but I can't find anything

Comment: Are you in the same class as NewbieProgram?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71653761/how-can-i-make-a-list-with-the-times-that-an-integer-occurs-in-another-list

Comment: hum, no i'm not, but i am a beginner

Comment: WHy would you want that result? You can't tell what those counts refer to.

Comment: Just convert it to a `list` using the `list` constructor: `x = list(c1.values())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn any iterable (including a `dict_values`) into a list by passing it to the builtin `list` constructor:

```
x = list(c1.values())
```

Never use builtin names like `list` or `dict` as variable names; if you do, like you did here:

```
list = [2,2,3,3]
```

you won't be able to use the builtin `list` any more because you've overwritten its name.  You'll need to edit your code to change the name of that variable before trying to use `list(c1.values())`.

Comment: note: you can technically "get it back" by doing something like `list = type([])`.  But just don't overwrite it in the first place.

Comment: or just `del list` since `list` is in the built-in namespace, and `list = whatever` would modify the global or local namespace, so it *shadows* the built-in lis

Answer (score 0):

The values returned by calling `.values()` on a dictionary are wrapped within a `dict_values` object. You can convert it into a normal list using:

```
x = list(c1.values())
```

Or, using your loop logic, but applying it directly to `Counter` and within a list-comprehension:

```
x = [v for v in Counter(list).values()]
```

Also as a general hint I would avoid using the names of python builtins such as `list` as variable names as that can cause problems and unexpected behaviours.